# What is the x++ equivalent for HASKELL

Tags: haskell

I started to learn functional programming for my assigment, I try to count, how many times compares if statement is proper i mean I want to put n++ after the command x > maxTail for display to last value of n

```
maxList :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maxList [x] = x  
maxList (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maxList xs
```

Comment: So you're counting the number of comparisons done? Define n as a parameter and increment it each call

Comment: I do not know how to do it, can you show me

Comment: How would you write the function in a different programming language?

Comment: int array[] = {2, 5, 3, 8, 4, 3};
  for (c = 1; c < 6; c++)
  {
    if (array[c] < array[c-1])
    {
       a++;
    }
  }

Comment: @ArdaGEZEK I'm still unclear on what you want. Your comment seems to indicate that you want a function that counts the number of pairs of consecutive increasing numbers, but the name of `maxList` and its type signature suggest otherwise. `maxList` returns an `Ord a => a`, but shouldn't it return an `Int`? As an example, should the result of using a list of `Date`s on `maxList` be one of those `Date`s? I would gladly help you, but please provide these details first.

Comment: I want to count how many times it this procedure that condition (list [c] < list [c-1]). 
please think some numbers inside a list
let say list =  [2,5,3,8,4,3] than i want to compere those elements in case  
for(x=1;x<=6;x++){
if(list [c] < list [c-1]) a++
}
 after than display the value of a

Comment: Great, we understand your goal.  Now how has this attempt fallen short?  What has been done to try and address that shortcoming?

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to solve problems in one language the way you would in another language.

In Haskell values are immutable, don't go trying to get a for loop with mutable value (`a` in your case).

Giving an example the other way, I might print the numbers 1 to N in Haskell using `traverse_ print [1..n]`.  How would that look in C? First write a linked list library. Then write a lazy iterator that can make a linked list until some predicate (equal to n).  Then write a higher order function that takes a function pointer and traverses the iterator. Finally iterate over the linked list to print my numbers to standard out.  Obviously there are other solutions in C, but if you're asking for a direct translation that's what you get.

So don't ask "how to x++" - there is no direct translation of x++ into Haskell.  Instead try to solve, and ask for help on, the higher level task such as counting the number of times an element is greater than all following elements in the list.

Comment: An easier first step for the C implementation: implement GHC.

Comment: @amalloy I don't often wish SO had a "laugh" reaction, but I did for yours :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a mistake in your type signature. What you want to return is a number, not just whatever `Ord` type being fed into the function. For example, `String` is a member of the `Ord` typeclass, but you wouldn't want to return a `String`.

```
func :: (Ord a, Num b) => [a] -> b
```

Second, you need to recurse on the elements looking at two elements at a time. The trick to this is to have two base cases: one for the empty list, and one for a list with only one element:

```
func [] = 0
func [_] = 0
```

Once you have those two elements, the rest almost writes itself: is the condition true? if so, add 1 to the recursion; otherwise, just recurse.

```
func (x:y:xs) --Pattern match on two elements at a time
  | x < y = 1 + func (y:xs)
  | otherwise = func (y:xs)
```

One other way to do it is to use higher-order functions. This way, you can decompose the problem into sequential steps:

1. Make pairs of each element and their neighbour.
2. Compare the elements in each of those pairs.
3. Count the number of times that condition is true.

This translates as:

```
f xs = length $ filter (\(a, b) -> a < b) $ zip xs $ (tail xs)
--     |        |-----------------------|   |----------------|
--     |                  |                       step 1
--     |                step 2
--   step 3
```

As you can see, functional programming takes completely different routes to problem-solving than imperative programming. This is why sometimes things just don't translate or correspond from one paradigm to another.